# PnP Provisioning Engine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, xml, pnp

How do I visually generate the XML for provisioning of a custom SharePoint List, instead of writing the XML manually?
can I use a "List Template"

I have the latest and greatest December release of the "PnP Provisioning Engine" running and working. But I desperately need documentation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create a new empty Sharepoint site, just for this purpose (a rootsite of a sitecollection works best) and then just create the list you need using the web user interface like you normally would.

Then just use the following Powershell commands (assuming your are using SharePoint Enterprise on premise):

```
Connect-SPOnline -Url http://yourlocalserver
Get-SPOProvisioningTemplate "C:\temp\template.xml" -Handlers Lists
```

If you do not specify -handlers Lists, all artifacts from the site will be extracted.

In the XML file that is generated (in this example c:\temp\template.xml) there will be a section  which includes a  section for each of the lists in your site.